# Find how many files on linux

Tags: linux

find / -xdev | wc -l

This is a command I found.
COuld anybody help me understand what is -xdev and what is wc -l?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please do one round of research before posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `find(1)` man page:

```
    -xdev  Don't descend directories on other filesystems.
```

`find` won't cross mount points.

From the `wc(1)` man page:

```
NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

 ...

       -l, --lines
              print the newline counts
```

`wc` counts the number of lines being piped in.

Answer (score 0):

try ls -l | wc -l this will count number of files and folders in any directory.